# jquery dialog widget not passing my form value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have table like image bellow where i create from query to databases, each row have button  when onclick will be prompt dialog box (i use jquery dialog widget)
[image: image 1]

this myform html code

```
<form action="prodi_tampil_mhs.php" method="post" name="form_tambah_cl_wisudawan" id="form_tambah_cl_wisudawan">
```

this my php code where i create the table from query database

```
while ($fetch_dbsi_mhsw=mysql_fetch_array($query_dbsi_mhsw)) {
$no++;
echo" <tr>
<td>$no</td>
<td>$fetch_dbsi_mhsw[NIM]</td>
<td>$fetch_dbsi_mhsw[Name]</td>
<td style=\"text-align: center;\"><input name=\"bt_tambah_calon_wisudawan\" id=\"bt_tambah_calon_wisudawan\" type=\"image\" src=\"buttonTambah.png\" alt=\"Tambah\" align=\"middle\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\" class=\"bt_tambah_calon_wisudawan\"   /></td></tr>";}
```

and my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bt_tambah_calon_wisudawan").click(function(){
        var value1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
        var value2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
        // Here's the text of the dialog box 
        var dialog = $("<div style='display: none'><p>Anda akan menambahkan "+value1 + " " + value2 + " sebagai calon wisudawan?</p></div>").appendTo("body");
        // This is the button on the form
        var form = $("#form_tambah_cl_wisudawan")
        // The form button was pressed - open the dialog
        $(dialog).dialog({
            title: "Konvirmasi Penambahan Data",
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            width: 600,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Tambah": function () {
                     // This will invoke the form's action - putatively deleting the resources on the server
                     $(form).submit();
                     $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    // Don't invoke the action, just close the dialog
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
 });
```

my  dialog box appear (like image 2) 
[image: image 2]

when i click button "tambah" in dialog box my value in form not passing. any mistake in my jquery code? any help?

Comment: You are not doing any thing with `value1` and `value2`,  simplest solution is to add 2 hidden fields in form then set the value

Comment: i have add 2 hidden fields in my form but not working, is there a way to passing the value from jquery code? because how submit button know which one from my row  value to pass?

Comment: Set value like `$("#hiddenFieldIdForValue1").val(value1)`

Comment: i have added hiddenFieldIdForValue1 and 2 in my php cde and jquery code, but nothing happen, then i change my form method to "get" and i see in my url filed like this prodi_tampil_mhs.php?hiddenFieldIdForValue1=A111002&hiddenFieldIdForValue2=la+i‌​min+lagi%0D%0A++++&hiddenFieldIdForValue1=A111002&hiddenFieldIdForValue2=la+imin+‌​lagi&hiddenFieldIdForValue1=A111003&hiddenFieldIdForValue2=la+imin+lagilagi, so the buuton passing all the value from table. I just want value from  row  where the buton i click.

Answer (score 1):

replace  `$(form).submit();` with `form.submit();` as you have already stored selector `$("#form_tambah_cl_wisudawan")` to `var form`.

Comment: thanks, i have edit my code also add like Satpal sugest, but not working yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you just refer the form  by `id` selector and `submit()` the form , then the operation goes as expected.

**JS CODE :**

```
 $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "Modal",
    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function () {
            $('#form_tambah_cl_wisudawan').submit();
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
         "No": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback(false);
        }
      }
  });
```

**Live Demo @ JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/vvjj8/7506/**